# The cells in my collectionView are repeated. Which is the error?

Tags: ios, swift

I`m working on a project where I have to take the forecast data from the internet by using a method that takes the city name as a parameter. This information has to be shown in a collectionViewCell that also has a tableView. The problem is that the collectionViewCells are repeated but the information inside the array which contains the cities is not repeated.
If the information in the array says [Paris, Madrid, Washington], the cells appear as Paris, Madrid, Paris

```
import UIKit

class AddNewCityViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var LabelTextField: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cityTextField: UITextField!

var cityName:String!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ForecastCollectionViewController.addNewCityName(_:)), name: message, object: self)


}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func addNewCity(sender: AnyObject) {

    cityName = cityTextField.text!
    var  cityNameDict = [String: String]()
    cityNameDict["cityName"] = cityName

    if cityTextField.text! != "" {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(message, object: nil, userInfo:cityNameDict)
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

    } else {
        noTextAlert()
    }
}

    func noTextAlert () {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Campo de texto vacío", message: "Escriba el nombre de la ciudad.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let accept = UIAlertAction(title: "Aceptar", style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in
        }

        alertController.addAction(accept)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

}

//Collection View Controller

```
class ForecastCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var infoLabel: UILabel!
var cityNames:[String] = []
var cityData = [CityData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    infoLabel.text = "Pulsa + para agrega una nueva ciudad"

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ForecastCollectionViewController.addNewCityName(_:)), name: message, object: nil)

}
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print ("Number of items: \(cityData.count)")
    return  cityData.count
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("La ciudad agregada es \(cityData[indexPath.row].name!)")

    let collectionCell = self.collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ForecastCollectionCell

    for item in cityData {
    collectionCell.currentCity = item
    collectionCell.current = item.name!
    print("Es " + item.name!)
    }


    return collectionCell
}

@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("segue1", sender: nil)
}

func addNewCityName(notification: NSNotification) {

    let cityNameDict : [String:String!] = notification.userInfo as! [String:String!]
    let cityName = cityNameDict["cityName"]
    self.cityNames.append(cityName!)

    WeatherBase.sharedInstance.weatherDataWith(cityName!, completion: {(city) -> Void in
        print ("Se ejecuto el closure")
        let cityForecast = city.forecasts
        let name = city.name
        let countryISO = city.countryISO

        let newCity = CityData(name: name!, countryISO: countryISO!, forecasts: cityForecast!)

        self.cityData.append(newCity)
        self.collectionView!.reloadData()
        self.infoLabel.text = ""
        }
    )

    print("Se agregó \(cityName!) a la lista de ciudades.")

}

@IBAction func quitCity(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Desea eliminar esta ciudad", message: "Me falta completar esto :)", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let yes = UIAlertAction(title: "Sí", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
        self.cityData.removeLast()
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
    let no = UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel) { (action) -> Void in

    }


    alertController.addAction(yes)
    alertController.addAction(no)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

//CollectionViewCellCotroller

```
class ForecastCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



@IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var countryNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var countryTemperatureLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var forecastTableView: UITableView!

var currentCity = CityData()
var current = CityData().name

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    forecastTableView.delegate = self
    forecastTableView.dataSource = self


    print ("Llego información de: \(currentCity.name)")


}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return  currentCity.forecasts.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let weatherCell = forecastTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("weatherTableCell", forIndexPath:  indexPath) as! WeatherTableViewCell

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    let myStringafd = formatter.stringFromDate(currentCity.forecasts[indexPath.row].time!)
    weatherCell.dateLabel.text = myStringafd

    weatherCell.temperatureLabel.text = String(currentCity.forecasts[indexPath.row].temperature) + "ºC"
    weatherCell.maxTemperatureLabel.text = String(currentCity.forecasts[indexPath.row].maximumTemperature) + "ºC"
    weatherCell.minTemperatureLabel.text = String(currentCity.forecasts[indexPath.row].minimumTemperature) + "ºC"
    weatherCell.backgroundImage.image = currentCity.forecasts[indexPath.row].background
    weatherCell.weatherDescriptionLabel.text = currentCity.forecasts[indexPath.row].weatherDescription
    weatherCell.weatherDescriptionLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    weatherCell.iconImageView.image = currentCity.forecasts[indexPath.row].icon

    for item in currentCity.forecasts {
    countryNameLabel.text = "\(current!), \(currentCity.countryISO!)"
    countryTemperatureLabel.text = String(item.temperature!) + "ºC"
    }
    return weatherCell
  }
}
```

I´ve been thinking that the error is in the cellForRowAtItem, but I can`t see it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath is called every time a cell is set, so you can follow almost the same logic with tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath, the difference is the layout and scroll direction which changes the position of the cell in the collection and therefore the position of the data displayed

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("La ciudad agregada es \(cityData[indexPath.row].name!)")

    let collectionCell = self.collectionView!.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("collectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ForecastCollectionCell

    collectionCell.currentCity = cityData[indexPath.row]
    collectionCell.current = cityData[indexPath.row].name!
    print("Es " + cityData[indexPath.row].name!)    

    return collectionCell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in fact why does the cell get repeated? Is there any problem with the indexpath?

Comment: Glad I helped you. Because of the for-loop the cell always ended with the last item when in fact  the data for your array "cityData" must be parallel one by one to the data displayed in the cell (cell1 == city1, cell2 == city2...)

Comment: So which could probably be a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried the solution I posted? Maybe the problem is in the way you are adding collection cells info. Try debugging adding this line before return: `print("ip-row\(indexPath.row) ip-section\(indexPath.section) city\(cityData[indexPath.row].name!)")` the result should be: `ip-row0 ip-section0 cityParis
ip-row1 ip-section0 cityMadrid
ip-row2 ip-section0 cityLondon`

Answer (score 0):

Check how many no of rows are there in your No of Rows per section method

Print --> currentCity.forecasts.count